# Can I run iostat on a Synology?

Tags: linux, storage-area-network, io, synology

I have a Synology RS812RP+ which I'm using for a little bit of departmental testing. I've stuffed a bunch of SSD disks in it, and I'm curious about monitoring the disk IO.

iostat doesn't come pre-installed on the synology and it doesn't have the tools to build it. Does anyone have any advice about getting iostat running in this environment?

Answer (score 6):

You can install dstat as a replacement for iostat

```
dstat - 0.7.0-1 - dstat is a versatile replacement for vmstat, iostat, netstat, nfsstat, and ifstat
```

You can install it by using `ipkg` which allows you to download other tools as well.
See the following links:

http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/Overview_on_modifying_the_Synology_Server,_bootstrap,_ipkg_etc#Bootstrap

http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/What_kind_of_CPU_does_my_NAS_have

Comment: dead links, answer not complete anymore

Answer (score 0):

Zorlack, I am new to Synology (we just got a DS1812+).  Mine is running BusyBox 1.16, and I think it's up-to-date... apparently BusyBox 1.18 has iostat (http://free-electrons.com/blog/busybox118/) so I'm sure you could get it running somehow.  I'd poke around the Synology Wiki and maybe ask over at their community wiki. Looks like you're not the only one though, check out http://forum.synology.com/enu/search.php?sid=59a2416beef28ed46b8c6b3068bb74ee

Comment: I saw that 1.18 has iostat... I think building and installing BusyBox for that environment may be outside my skills. Particularly since there are no compiler tools on the Synology.